# Excel 2013の「実行時エラー'9'」について

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2013 で下記のマクロを実行しているときに

> 実行時エラー'9':インデックスが有効範囲にありません

と出ます。

```
Sub test()
    Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = False
End Sub
```

「Sheet1」があるのにも関わらず、上記のようなエラーが出ます。
どうすれば「Sheet1」を非表示にできるのでしょうか？

Comment: `Book2.xlsm` は同一 PC 上に存在しているのでしょうか？

Comment: Shironeさん
はい。同一PC上に存在してます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")でワークブック本体を取得するには、そのファイルを開いていないとダメです。
そしてWorksheetsには名前ではなくindexを渡します。つまり何番目のシートかという数字です。
1番目のシートであれば`.Worksheets(1)`でOKです。
※一般的な言語の配列のように0から始まりません。

そしてもう一つ注意点。
Excelでは全てのシートを非表示にできません。
なのでSheet1しかそのファイルに存在していない場合、なんぼがんばっても非表示にできません。
もう一つシートを追加してやれば非表示にできるハズです。

---

今調べてみたらWorksheets("名前")でも行けるみたいですね...出直してきます。(´・ω・`)

どうやら、ファイルを開いてないと`実行時エラー'9'`が出るみたいです。
とりあえず、メソッドチェーンを使わずに、どの段階でエラーが起きているのか特定するのが良いかと思います。以下のようにして実行するとドコで落ちるでしょう？

```
Sub Test()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  ws.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: 豚吐露さん

そのコードを実行しても「実行時エラー'9'」としか出てきません。

Comment: 自分が書いたコードは、問題箇所を特定するためのコードで、正しく動くというコードではありません。
メニューの『表示』から『マクロ』→『マクロの表示』を選択。Testが表示されてるはずなので、選択してから『ステップ イン』ボタンを押す。F8を押して行くと1行ずつ実行できるので、どこで落ちてるか分かると思うんですが...どこで落ちていますか？

Comment: @さかえ  豚吐露さんの仰る通りで、`Excelでは全てのシートを非表示にできません。なのでSheet1しかそのファイルに存在していない場合、なんぼがんばっても非表示にできません。もう一つシートを追加してやれば非表示にできるハズです。` の通りだと思います。あと、Excel 上でファイルを開いてないと実行時エラーを吐きます。事前に `Book2.xlsm` を Excel 上で開いておく必要がありますね。

Comment: 豚吐露さん
 Set wb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")
のところで落ちます。

Shironeさん
アドバイスありがとうございます。

Comment: ファイルの拡張子を間違っておりました。
アドバイス感謝致します。
ありがとうございました。